# Laravel 5.8 419 page expire Exception in Bluehost Server

Tags: laravel

i just uploaded a Laravel 5.8  Project in my Bluehost hosting. Every thing is set. When login to the application it is showing 419 Page Expired Exception. I used @csrf and in post request.

in my local machine it is running perfectly. When i purchased domain bluehost provided me wordpress hosting and i removed all wordpress files in the domain and uploaded Laravel Project.

Comment: What is your `SESSION_DRIVER` value in your Bluehost Server `.env` file?

Comment: hi aceraven SESSIOn_DRIVER is set to file.

Comment: Do you have `SESSION_DOMAIN` in the `.env` file?

Comment: no i dont have SESSION_DOMAIN in the .env file

Comment: Is your bluehost server shared or dedicated?

Comment: Can you try running this command in your bluehost server: `chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache`

Comment: it is a shared server.

Comment: Can you try running the command I provided you above

Comment: yes i run the command but no luck

Comment: same files i uploaded in my own Bluehost multi domain hosting and there it is showing access denied to the user. though i provided database name,user id and password properly. dont know what is happening.

Comment: I think you have to set the proper permissions to the folders.. Can you try running these commands: `find storage -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;` and `find storage -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;`

Comment: Tell me if there's an error running this commands

Comment: Is the `framework/sessions` directory writable?

Comment: it is showing error find:missing  argument to -exec

Comment: Hi All i got the answer , it was due to PDP Exception and i made changes in config->database.php and added option=>[
                     \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true ].

Answer (score 0):

You may make a route like

```
Route::get('/clear',function(){
    Artisan::call('view:clear');
    Artisan::call('route:clear');
    Artisan::call('config:cache');
    Artisan::call('cache:clear');
});
```

then run from the browser like

```
http://your-app.com/clear
```

Hope this may help you. Thanks.

Comment: No luck imran. i checked the Permission also it is 775.